# XAMPP MySQL shutdown unexpected - cannot open tablespace

Tags: mysql, xampp

I recently reinstalled XAMPP to get PHP5.5

I created a new database when doing this, importing it via an SQL export created by phpMyAdmin.  (It is a copy of a live database to allow me to develop on my localhost).

After installing and restarting the PC everything worked.

At the end of the day I shutdown and went away.  When I next turned the computer on.  I got a MySQL shutdown unexpected error.  Thinking it could be the new installation I reinstalled again.  After restarting the PC after the resinstall, everything works again.  So I reimport the database, no issues all day.

However I come back again today and the error has returned.
Anyone know what is causing the error?  File permissions seem to be okay, file in question (see log) says all users has write/read/etc.. permissions.

**mysql_error.log**

```
2013-09-18 12:18:48 6556 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
2013-09-18 12:18:48 1b60 InnoDB: Warning: Using innodb_additional_mem_pool_size is DEPRECATED. This option may be removed in future releases, together with the option innodb_use_sys_malloc and with the InnoDB's internal memory allocator.
2013-09-18 12:18:48 6556 [Note] InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
2013-09-18 12:18:48 6556 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows interlocked functions
2013-09-18 12:18:48 6556 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.3
2013-09-18 12:18:48 6556 [Note] InnoDB: Not using CPU crc32 instructions
2013-09-18 12:18:48 6556 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 16.0M
2013-09-18 12:18:48 6556 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2013-09-18 12:18:48 6556 [Note] InnoDB: Highest supported file format is Barracuda.
2013-09-18 12:18:48 6556 [Note] InnoDB: The log sequence numbers 0 and 0 in ibdata files do not match the log sequence number 6000837 in the ib_logfiles!
2013-09-18 12:18:48 6556 [Note] InnoDB: Database was not shutdown normally!
2013-09-18 12:18:48 6556 [Note] InnoDB: Starting crash recovery.
2013-09-18 12:18:48 6556 [Note] InnoDB: Reading tablespace information from the .ibd files...
2013-09-18 12:18:48 6556 [ERROR] InnoDB: Attempted to open a previously opened tablespace. Previous tablespace mysql/innodb_table_stats uses space ID: 1 at filepath: .\mysql\innodb_table_stats.ibd. Cannot open tablespace testserver/tbl_users which uses space ID: 1 at filepath: .\testserver\tbl_users.ibd
InnoDB: Error: could not open single-table tablespace file .\testserver\tbl_users.ibd
InnoDB: We do not continue the crash recovery, because the table may become
InnoDB: corrupt if we cannot apply the log records in the InnoDB log to it.
InnoDB: To fix the problem and start mysqld:
InnoDB: 1) If there is a permission problem in the file and mysqld cannot
InnoDB: open the file, you should modify the permissions.
InnoDB: 2) If the table is not needed, or you can restore it from a backup,
InnoDB: then you can remove the .ibd file, and InnoDB will do a normal
InnoDB: crash recovery and ignore that table.
InnoDB: 3) If the file system or the disk is broken, and you cannot remove
InnoDB: the .ibd file, you can set innodb_force_recovery > 0 in my.cnf
InnoDB: and force InnoDB to continue crash recovery here.
```

Answer (score 0):

it's a bummer to troubleshoot. usually that error comes from a database created on one ersion of mysql and imported on another. Happened to me between 5.5 and 5.6. You can re-create the database from scratch using the already existing code and data for each table, and it should then be issue-free